# use jquery in global javascript function with browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify

I am trying to create a bundle file that will work like an embed script. I need jquery in it and I am trying it like this. I can use jQuery but I need to use a document. ready function. I was trying something better because There will be multiple places I need jQuery. Is there a better solution?

```
window.fmlead = (settings) => {
      const samplefunction = (samplearg) => {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#main").html("Omg it is working");  // this is working
        })
        $("#main2").html("this is my tset"); // this is not working
      };
      const init = () => {
        samplefunction();
      };
    
      init();
    }
```

I tried this code as well but it doesn't work. It is giving me an error `index.html:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: fmlead is not defined`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.fmlead = (settings) => {
    const samplefunction = (samplearg) => {
      $("#main2").html("this is my test"); // should work now
    };
    const init = () => {
      samplefunction();
    };

    init();
  };
});
```

Comment: The second one is not going to define the function until the document is done loading....

Comment: hmmm is there a way to create a similar script like this or any example ?

Comment: What is wrong with the first way you have done it?